# How did The Founders make Odo sick?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, plot-device

In Deep Space Nine episode S04E26 "Broken Link", Odo found himself suddenly afflicted with an illness that caused his shape-shifting abilities to destablize. He eventually went to the Founders for help, where the Female Changeling admitted that they made him sick on purpose so that he would have to come home. No mention was made of how they did it, though.

**Has any source explained how The Founders afflicted Odo with this sickness?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did the Great Link transform Odo into a human?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69155/how-did-the-great-link-transform-odo-into-a-human)

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: I don't see how.  This question is about how the founders got Odo to even show up in the first place, not what they did to him after he arrived.

Comment: @Kevin Ah, you are correct, I misinterpreted. Close vote retracted.

Comment: I was always under the impression that Aroma (the woman Garak introduced Odo to) was a changeling and passed the virus to him... Could be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He was infected by Weyoun.

From [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/496.txt) for the episode *To The Death* (4x23):

> Weyoun looks at Odo for a beat, then gives him a good-
>       natured clap on the shoulder. (In case anyone's 
>       interested, when he touches Odo, Weyoun is purposely 
>       infecting Odo with the disease that almost kills him in 
>       "BROKEN LINK.")

**This is considered non-canon since it's never mentioned on-screen**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where he got this information, but in SFDebris's [Biography of Weyoun](http://sfdebris.com/videos/startrek/d556.php), it's mentioned that during the episode To The Death, Weyoun transmitted the disease to Odo by touching his shoulder.

SFDebris is usually one to preface if he's talking about fan theories, interviews with creators, or novelizations, so the way he says it sounds as if it was settled in the series proper, but I personally don't recall it.